# Energy and momentum transfer before and after breaking a light string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, string

[image: before/after]

Imagine two masses are connected by a light string, which then snaps - how does this change the speed of the masses?

My understanding so far is that the average speed of the two masses is unchanged
$\left(\langle\mathbf{u}(t)\rangle=\mathbf{u}_0\right)$ - but that we've added a time-dependent component as the string now oscillates back and forth, perturbing slightly the motion of the masses.

If we're interested in the long term behaviour of this system as it orbits in some constant smooth background potential, does the motion of the each mass differ substantially from the case where the string is instantaneously removed?

Comment: No problem. Try including your working and thought. Also, find the specific concept which you'd need to know (but don't know yet) to solve this problem and then rephrase the question to focus more on that specific concept rather than the situation itself. For example, a better question could be, "What happens to the tension in the string after it's cut?" This way your question would be more of a conceptual and simultaneously be helpful to many other visitors. Doing this will improve the chances of this question being reopened :)

Answer (score 1):

If they are stationary, it means that:

1. Either the tension on stationary ball get's counter balanced by opposite force.
2. There is no tension in the first place.

If first is the case, the balls will keep moving governed by Newton's laws and 'external' force acting on them.

Comment: not sure that's true - the string could break at its maximum extent, and at the moment of breaking the balls would both be stationary even though the spring is stretched

Comment: Could you please elaborate? In general for string tension to occur, forces at its end must be applied. Assuming the string breaks after exceeding some tension, the balls will move according to the 'remaining' forces acting on them.